# React not rerendering after action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have an application that has a dashboard with a list of soups. Every soup has the ability to be a daily soup. So each soup has a button that if clicked, triggers an action to update my MongoDB to make the soup a daily soup. When a soup is a daily soup, it then has 3 buttons: Remove, Low, Out. If any of these buttons are clicked they trigger an action to update my MongoDB to update that particular soup. The issue I have is that when any of these buttons are clicked, it performs the action but it is not re-rendered on the screen. I have to manually refresh the page to see that it actually worked.

Note: I am using reduxThunk to immediately dispatch the action (see code below)

I have tried using

```
Object.assign({}, state, action.payload)
```

in my reducer to be sure to avoid changing the state directly.

I also tried rewriting my reducer with:

```
case "UPDATE_SOUP":
      return {
        ...state,
        isDaily: action.payload.isDaily,
        isLow: action.payload.isLow,
        isOut: action.payload.isOut
      };
```

React Soup Component:

```
class Soup extends Component {
  render() {
    const { soup } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <div key={soup.name} className="card">
          <div
            className={`card-header ${
              soup.isDaily ? "alert alert-primary" : null
            }`}
          >
            {soup.isDaily ? (
              <span className="badge badge-primary badge-pill">Daily Soup</span>
            ) : (
              "Soup"
            )}
          </div>
          <div className="card-body">
            <h5 className="card-title">{soup.name}</h5>
            <p className="card-text">
              {soup.isLow ? (
                <span className="badge badge-warning badge-pill">
                  This soup is marked as LOW.
                </span>
              ) : null}
              {soup.isOut ? (
                <span className="badge badge-dark badge-pill">
                  This soup is marked as OUT.
                </span>
              ) : null}
            </p>

            {soup.isDaily ? (
              <div>
                <button
                  onClick={() =>
                    this.props.updateSoup(soup._id, {
                      isDaily: false,
                      isLow: false,
                      isOut: false
                    })
                  }
                  className="btn btn-danger "
                >
                  Remove
                </button>
                <button
                  onClick={() =>
                    this.props.updateSoup(soup._id, {
                      isLow: true
                    })
                  }
                  className="btn btn-warning"
                >
                  Getting Low
                </button>
                <button
                  onClick={() =>
                    this.props.updateSoup(soup._id, {
                      isOut: true
                    })
                  }
                  className="btn btn-dark"
                >
                  Ran Out
                </button>
              </div>
            ) : (
              <button
                onClick={event =>
                  this.props.updateSoup(soup._id, {
                    isDaily: true
                  })
                }
                className="btn btn-primary"
              >
                Make Daily
              </button>
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps({ soupsReducer }) {
  return { soupsReducer };
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  actions
)(Soup);
```

React SoupList Component (To show all Soups):

```
class SoupList extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.allSoups();
  }

  renderSoup() {
    const { soupsReducer } = this.props;
    if (soupsReducer.length > 0) {
      return soupsReducer.map(soup => {
        if (soup.name !== "date") {
          return <Soup key={soup._id} soup={soup} />;
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    console.log("SoupListProps=", this.props);
    return <div>{this.renderSoup()}</div>;
  }
}

function mapStateToProps({ soupsReducer, dateReducer }) {
  return { soupsReducer, dateReducer };
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  actions
)(SoupList);
```

Action:

```
export const updateSoup = (id, update) => async dispatch => {
  const res = await axios.put(`/api/allsoups/${id}`, update);
  dispatch({ type: "UPDATE_SOUP", payload: res.data });
};
```

Reducer:

```
export default function(state = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "FETCH_SOUPS":
      return action.payload;
    case "ALL_SOUPS":
      return action.payload;
    case "UPDATE_SOUP":
      return action.payload;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are re-writing your whole state in every action by doing

```
return action.payload;
```

You need to do something like

```
return { ...state, someStateKey: action.payload.data.someKey }
```

Where depending on the action type you pull the required data from the response and set that in your state.

If you can provide more info on the response, I can update the answer with more specific details

Comment: the action.payload or res.data that I get back = {_id: 'numbersAndLetters', name: 'soupName', isDaily: true, isOut: false, isLow: false, ... }

Comment: I tried what you suggested above and it did not work

Answer (score 0):

My thoughts are revolving around this part of your code...

```
export const updateSoup = (id, update) => async dispatch => {
  const res = await axios.put(`/api/allsoups/${id}`, update);
  dispatch({ type: "UPDATE_SOUP", payload: res.data });
};

export default function(state = [], action) {

        // ...code...

    case "UPDATE_SOUP":
      return action.payload;

        // ...code...

    }
}
```

Try this:

Identify the souptype AND the change to your action...

```
dispatch({ type: "UPDATE_SOUP", payload: res.data, souptype: id, update: update });
```

Update the state to the souptype to your reducer...

```
export default function(state = [], action) {
    case "UPDATE_SOUP":
      const newstate = action.payload;
      neswstate.soups[action.souptype] = action.isDaily ? true : false;
      return newstate;
```

Of course, why won't this work?  Simply because I'm *guessing* what kind of state you have and how the soups are stored in this state.  There is no constructor or state definition in your code, so, you'll need to adjust what's above to match how your state is defined.